# windows admin center connection issues

Tags: windows, server, powershell-4.0

The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

I have recently installed on a WM windows admin center, created the certificate imported the thumbprint and all that, everything works fine, but when I am trying to connect to a server or computer it pops up with this error. 
I am using a dedicated VM only for this. 
 1. I have no issues finding the computers from search option in Active Directory. 
 2. I am trying from the VM and also my local computer, same situation. 
 Can someone tell me what should I do in order to make it work ? 
I really can't find a lot of topics on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue of ports not being open, required target host ports open 5985(HTTP) 5986(HTTPS)